# Adafruit feather 32u4 FONA sleep modes

Tags: adafruit

I need to put Adafruit FONA to sleep in order to conserve battery. (The GSM module is no problem). I've searched the net for solutions with
Adafruit feather 32u4 FONA and
Adafruit RTC FeatherWing RTC module
Rumour has it that it should be possible to put the 32u4 to sleep and wake it up with a hardware interrupt from the RTC.
Anyone has any info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using the library LowPower:
https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power